# Trouble setting up dynamic font application in Angular with Tailwind

Tags: css, angular, tailwind-css

I'm encountering an issue while attempting to dynamically set the font application-wide based on user choice in an Angular project with Tailwind CSS. [fonts-not-applied.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Siy26.png)

The guide I followed to set-up Tailwind with Angular:
[Install Tailwind CSS with Angular](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/angular)

And here's what I've done so far:

In my `tailwind.config.js`, I've configured the fonts as follows:

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.{html,ts}",
  ],
  theme: {
    fontFamily: {
      'sans': ['Inter', 'sans-serif'],
      'serif': ['Lora', 'serif'],
      'mono': ['Inconsolata', 'monospace']
    },
...rest of the config
```

Additionally, I've imported the necessary Google Fonts in my `styles.css`:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inconsolata:wght@200..900&family=Inter+Tight:ital,wght@0,100..900;1,100..900&family=Lora:ital,wght@0,400..700;1,400..700&display=swap");
```

Despite verifying that the `font-sans`, `font-mono` or `font-serif` classes have been correctly applied in the DOM, Tailwind seems to be ignoring the font-family settings. However, if I apply the font-family directly to an element using a static class like class="font-mono", it works as expected.

What could be causing this issue and how can I resolve it to dynamically apply the font-family based on user choice? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.